# How to retrieve data from sqlite database by clicking button and display in a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm actually confused instead of looking for any new thing to add or correct it confused me and now I don't know what to add nor correct

I want to retrieve data from the sqlite database from clicking the button SEARCH TRIP then I want it to display in a listview by which I would also be able to click one of the listview and click it to direct me to another page displaying the info, but I'm still having doubts in that

in my logcat, there are no errors upon running and when I click the button SEARCH TRIP nothing happens there is no error I'm having these classes: DATABASEHELPER, LISTVIEWCURSORADAPTERACTIVITY, TRIPSDBADAPTER

The button is in the fragment since I'm having tabs in one of them the button is situated on the fragment when I implement the View.onclicklistener the on the method when I specify one of the classes such as LISTVIEWCURSORADAPTERACTIVITY or TRIPSDBADAPTER its showing error where should I put the connection of the button

If possible, can anyone please help me with the code what have I done wrong?

DatabaseHelper.java

```
import android.content.Contect;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stallion_db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "one-way";
public static final String COL_1 = "depart from";
public static final String COL_2 = "arrive_to";
public static final String COL_3 = "report_time";
public static final String COL_4 = "depart_on";
public static final String COL_5 = "departure time";
public static final String COL_6 = "price";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "" + " (NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " depart_from TEXT, arrive_to TEXT, report_time VARCHAR, depart_on DATE, departure_time VARCHAR," +
            " price INTEGER); ");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO oneway values (1, mombasa, nairobi, 10:30AM, 25-12-2015, 11:00AM, 900)");
db.execSQL("SELECT FROM oneway WHERE depart_from = mombasa and arrive_to = nairobi");
}       


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Getting All Contacts
public List<ConstructorOneWay> getAlltrips() {
    List<ConstructorOneWay> tripList = new ArrayList<ConstructorOneWay>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;



    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ConstructorOneWay trip = new ConstructorOneWay();
            trip.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            trip.setDepart(cursor.getString(1));
            trip.setArrive(cursor.getString(2));
            trip.setReport(cursor.getString(3));
            trip.setdeparting(cursor.getString(4));
            trip.setprice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
            // Adding trips to list
            tripList.add(trip);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return tripList;
}



}
```

ListViewCursorAdapterActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ListViewCursorAdaptorActivity extends Activity {
private TripsdbAdapter dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;  

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.trip_listview);

    dbHelper = new TripsdbAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
    displayListView();
}

private void displayListView() {
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchallTrips();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            TripsdbAdapter.Depart_from,
            TripsdbAdapter.Arrive_to,
            TripsdbAdapter.Depart_on,
            TripsdbAdapter.Departure_time,
            TripsdbAdapter.Price,
    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.tv1,
            R.id.tv2,
            R.id.tv3,
            R.id.tv4,
            R.id.tv5,

    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.display_one_way_trip,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    }); }}
```

TripsdbAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class TripsdbAdapter {



//FOR DISPLAYING AFTER SEARCH

public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String Depart_from = "Depart from";
public static final String Arrive_to = "Arrive to";
public static final String Depart_on = "Depart on";
public static final String Departure_time = "Departure time";
public static final String Price = "Price";

private static final String TAG = "TripsdbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stallion_db";
private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "oneway";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private Context mCtx;

public TripsdbAdapter(Context mContext) {
    this.mCtx = mContext;
}


public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {Depart_from,
                        Arrive_to, Depart_on, Departure_time, Price},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    else {
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {Depart_from,
                         Arrive_to, Depart_on, Departure_time, Price},
                Depart_from + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public Cursor fetchallTrips() {

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {Depart_from,
                    Arrive_to, Depart_on, Departure_time, Price},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}


public void open() {
} }
```

logcat:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQT5c.png)

Comment: in open() method write mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: so my code is correct i just have to add that? what about adding the button where should i add? fragment class by implementing View.onclicklistener followed by onClick method? but then direct to to what class?

Comment: yes it said unfortunately the app has stopped

Comment: can you post log cat?

Comment: let me just post the whole thing

Comment: @Piyush posted the logcat

Comment: @Piyush how do i add the connection for the button to connect to the database

Comment: check my answer, dbHelper.open(); open the database

Comment: @Piyush  is it okay if i just change from MainActivity to other name since this is after main activity then this classes comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TripsdbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private Button btnGetList;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new TripsdbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        btnGetList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetList);
        btnGetList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayListView();
            }
        });
    }

private void displayListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchallTrips();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {TripsdbAdapter.ID ,TripsdbAdapter.Depart_from, TripsdbAdapter.Arrive_to, TripsdbAdapter.Depart_on, TripsdbAdapter.Departure_time, TripsdbAdapter.Price, };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2, R.id.tv3, R.id.tv4, R.id.tv5,R.id.tv6

        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        // as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.display_one_way_trip, cursor, columns, to, 0);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the
                // result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }

public class TripsdbAdapter {

        // FOR DISPLAYING AFTER SEARCH

        public static final String ID = "_id";
        public static final String Depart_from = "depart_from";
        public static final String Arrive_to = "arrive_to";
        public static final String Depart_on = "depart_on";
        public static final String Departure_time = "departure_time";
        public static final String Price = "price";

        private static final String TAG = "TripsdbAdapter";
        private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stallion_db";
        private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "oneway";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private Context mCtx;

        public TripsdbAdapter(Context mContext) {
            this.mCtx = mContext;
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        }

        public void close() {
            if (mDbHelper != null) {
                mDbHelper.close();
            }
        }

        public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
            Log.w(TAG, inputText);
            Cursor mCursor = null;
            if (inputText == null || inputText.length() == 0) {
                mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { Depart_from, Arrive_to, Depart_on, Departure_time, Price }, null, null, null, null, null);
            } else {
                mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { Depart_from, Arrive_to, Depart_on, Departure_time, Price }, Depart_from + " like '%" + inputText + "%'",
                        null, null, null, null, null);
            }
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;

        }

        public Cursor fetchallTrips() {

            Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]  {ID,Depart_from, Arrive_to, Depart_on, Departure_time, Price }, null, null, null, null, null);

            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }

        public void open() {
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stallion_db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "oneway";
    public static final String COL_1 = "depart_from";
    public static final String COL_2 = "arrive_to";
    public static final String COL_3 = "report_time";
    public static final String COL_4 = "depart_on";
    public static final String COL_5 = "departure_time";
    public static final String COL_6 = "price";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "" + " (NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + " depart_from TEXT, arrive_to TEXT, report_time VARCHAR, depart_on DATE, departure_time VARCHAR," + " price INTEGER); ");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO oneway values (1, 'mombasa', 'nairobi', '10:30AM', '25-12-2015', '11:00AM', 900)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO oneway values (2, 'abcd', 'nairobi', '10:30AM', '26-12-2015', '10:00AM', 800)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO oneway values (3, 'pqrs', 'nairobi', '10:30AM', '27-12-2015', '09:00AM', 700)");
        // db.execSQL("SELECT FROM oneway WHERE depart_from = mombasa and arrive_to = nairobi");
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<ConstructorOneWay> getAlltrips() {
        List<ConstructorOneWay> tripList = new ArrayList<ConstructorOneWay>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ConstructorOneWay trip = new ConstructorOneWay();
                trip.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                trip.setDepart(cursor.getString(1));
                trip.setArrive(cursor.getString(2));
                trip.setReport(cursor.getString(3));
                trip.setDeparting(cursor.getString(4));
                trip.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
                // Adding trips to list
                tripList.add(trip);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return tripList;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get All" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnGetList" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```